# js spawn python process - some python exceptions are ignored by python try-except handlers and send stderr to js

Tags: python, node.js, paramiko, child-process, spawn

I have some `js` code where I spawn `python` script:
**js code**

```
...
var childProcess = spawn(myPythonCode)
    .on('error', err => {
        # uncaught error handler
    })
...
```

**python code**

```
...
# configuration
ssh = SSHClient()
try:
    ssh.connect(credentials)
except SSHException:
    # do something on SSHException
    raise Exception('New exception text')
...
```

In my code I am trying to open **SSH connection** with `paramiko` and if credentials are wrong (for example - invalid host) `paramiko` raise `SSHException` which should be handled but it send `stderr` to `js` `childProcess` and uncaught error handler is killing python process.
Err log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2271, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 380, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 622, in _read_timeout
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2094, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2275, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Exception (client): Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2271, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 380, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 622, in _read_timeout
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2094, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2275, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

Any ideas how to handle it?

I expect to handle python error in python process, not in js